# Load and unload angular6 component

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular6, angular-components

I'm trying to create an image modal when an image is clicked. I've set it up so the child component loads when the image is clicked. The problem is that it can only be clicked once and after it closes it sets `display: none`.

It can be closed by clicking a close button in the child component. But I've only managed to do this with `display: none` in the CSS, making the component invisible but still active.

What I ultimately want is a way of unloading that child component when the close button is pressed. Or setting `opacity: 1` when the image in the parent is clicked again.

HTML Parent:

```
<app-image-modal
    *ngIf="clicked"
    [slice] = "slice"
    [clicked] = "clicked">
</app-image-modal>

<img src"img.png" (click)="imageClicked()"/>
```

TS Parent:

```
export class ImageComponent {
public clicked = false;

public imageClicked() {
    this.clicked = true;
}
}
```

HTML Child:

```
<section [ngClass]="{'hide': hide}">
  <div [ngClass]="{'active': show}">

    <img src"img.png" />

    <div class="close" (click)="hideModal()">
        <button>X</button>
    </div>

  </div>                                                              
</section>
```

TS Child:

```
export class ImageModalComponent implements OnInit {
public show = false;
public hide = false;

@Input() clicked: boolean;

public ngOnInit() {
    this.show = true;
}

public hideModal() {
    this.show = false;
    this.hide = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think you have your component communication backward**.

Info of closing should go from child to parent. To implement this : you can have an EventEmitter in your child component, and listen to it from the Parent component.

Then, if you want to unload the child component, you can use a boolean tied with an `*ngIf` for the child component in the template of the parent .

The fact that the modal is showed or not showed should be handled at the parent level (e.g. : no need for booleans show and hide in the child, and by the way you could handle this with only *one* boolean instead of two).

Why at the parent level ? because you want to *unload* the component, not merely hide it.

**Code example :**

** In the child component ** :

```
export class ImageModalComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() close = new EventEmitter();

    public hideModal() {
        this.close.emit(); // here we tell the parent that the "close" button has been clicked.
    }
}
```

In the child HTML, remove anything relying on "show" and "hide" (assume that the component is shown) :

```
<section>
  <div class="active">
  ...
```

** In the parent template : **

```
export class ImageComponent {

    public clicked = false;

    public imageClicked() {
        this.clicked = true;
    }

    public childCloseEventHandler(): void {
        this.clicked = false; // this will trigger the unload of the child, since you have `*ngIf="clicked"` for the child component
    }
}
```

HTML Parent:

```html
<app-image-modal
    *ngIf="clicked"
    [slice]="slice"
    (close)="childCloseEventHandler()">   <!-- I changed this line -->
</app-image-modal>

<img src"img.png" (click)="imageClicked()"/>
```